# Using Python to remove duplicated contents in cells in Excel

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python to remove the duplicated contents in the cells of an Excel Spreadsheet.

The data is in 1 column, in the original file. (names separated by “, ” in each cell)

```
Noah, Mason, Emily, Isabella, Emily
Liam, Madison, Mia, Ava, Mia
Jacob, Ethan, Jayden, Mia, Jayden
Mason, Emily, Daniel, Emily, Daniel
Madison, Mia, Sophia, Abigail, Sophia
Ethan, Jayden, Elizabeth, Madison, Elizabeth
Emily, Daniel, Olivia, Elizabeth, Olivia
Mia, Sophia, Isabella, Isabella
Jayden, Elizabeth, Ava, Ava
Daniel, Olivia, Mia, Mia
Sophia, Isabella, Emily, Emily
Elizabeth, Ava, Abigail, Abigail
Olivia, Mia, Madison, Madison
Isabella, Emily, Elizabeth, Elizabeth
```

Codes I worked out so far is:

```
old_file = open_workbook('c:\\Book1.xls',formatting_info=True)
old_sheet = old_file.sheet_by_index(0) 

new_file = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
new_sheet = new_file.add_sheet('Result', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for row_index in range(0, old_sheet.nrows):
    column_con = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    aaa = dict.fromkeys(column_con).keys()
    new_sheet.write(row_index, 0, aaa)

new_file.save('c:\\Book New 1.xls')
```

however when run, it removes all the duplicated letters, instead of the wanted words, and became:

```
a bEihM,oNmsyenIl
a diMmLo,sAvn
a cbEdihJM,ontye
a EDimM,onsyel
a bdgihM,onpsASl
a bEdihJM,onstyezl
a zEDihm,Olbtvyen
a bIihM,olpSes
a bedihJ,nAtvyEzl
a eDiMlOnv,
a bIihm,olpSyesE
a bEgihl,Atvez
a diM,Olsovn
a beIhml,istyEz
```

how can I have the duplicated names removed? Thanks.

Comment: what does `aaa` look like when you print it?

Comment: I'm having hard to to understand what is the actual content of your initial XLS sheet, and what is the expected result. Could you **edit** your question to clarify that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys()` takes a `sequence` and not a `string`

Try this:

```
for row_index in range(0, old_sheet.nrows):
    column_con = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value

    # First split into a list and convert to sequence
    column_con = tuple(column_con.split(', '))

    aaa = dict.fromkeys(column_con).keys()

    # Since aaa is a list of keys, you also need to join them in a string
    aaa = ', '.join(aaa)
    new_sheet.write(row_index, 0, aaa)
```

Answer (score -1):

use set to store the data you read from excel

```
data=xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\\I307658\\Desktop\\test.xlsx")
old_sheet = data.sheet_by_index(0) 
new_file = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
new_sheet = new_file.add_sheet('Result', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for row_index in range(0, old_sheet.nrows):
    column_con = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    print column_con
    aaa =set(column_con.split(","))

    print ', '.join(aaa)
    new_sheet.write(row_index, 0, ', '.join(aaa))

new_file.save("C:\\Users\\I307658\\Desktop\\Book New 1.xls")
```