# Pandas - Concat strings after groupby in column, ignore NaN, ignore duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nan, missing-data

Depending on the query, my DF can have a column with strings or a column with NaN.

Ex:

```
  ID     grams   Projects
0  891            4.0      NaN
1  725            9.0      NaN
```

or

```
  ID     grams   Projects
0  890            1.0      P1, P2
1  724            1.0      P1
2  880            1.0      P1, P2
3  943            1.0      P1
4  071            1.0      P1
```

I can handle one or the other, but when I try to make a function that is generic I'm failing miserably. I need to ignore the NaN at the end, because I'm sending this DF as JSON response and NaN gives me an invalid format.

The way I'm doing right now is:

```
#When Projects is a string
df['Projects'] = _df.groupby("ID")['External_Id'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x))

#When Projects is NaN
df['Projects'] = _df.groupby("ID")['External_Id'].apply(lambda x: "")
```

I tried to use `fillna()` and also to check the dtype of 'x' but it always returns as **object**, so I can't check whether it is a **str** or **NaN**

Also, the result of the 'Projects' column should not allow duplicates. Some rows when grouped by ID have important information which will be summed ('grams'), but the 'External_Id' should not appear more than once.
Ex:

```
  ID       grams      External_Id
0  890        1.0      P1
1  890        1.0      P2
2  890        1.0      P2
3  724        1.0      P1
4  724        1.0      P1
```

Result should be

```
  ID       grams      Projects
0  890        3.0      P1, P2
1  724        2.0      P1
```

And not

```
  ID       grams      Projects
0  890        1.0      P1, P2, P2
1  724        1.0      P1, P1
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to detect wheter the column has a NaN?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want to return a null string ("") if the column has a NaN because it is invalid in a JSON object.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore duplicates"? It's in the title, but it seems missing from the body of the question.

Comment: You are right, i forgot to explain that. I'll add to the body. I basically have some rows with the same ID and same Project. The other information on the rows are important to count/analyze, but the projects, for example, should appear only once and not "P1, P1, P1..." when concatenated.

Comment: Do all the NaNs relate to the same project or not?
It would be nice if you could give an example for input data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you start with

```
In [37]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [1, None, 2, 4], 'c': ['foo', 'sho', 'sha', 'bar']})

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
   a    b    c
0  1  1.0  foo
1  1  NaN  foo
2  2  2.0  sha
3  2  4.0  bar
```

Then you can apply the same function to either `b` or `c`, taking care of the NaNs and duplicates:

```
In [44]: df.b.groupby(df.a).apply(lambda x: '' if x.isnull().any() else ','.join(set(x.astype(str).values)))
Out[44]: 
a
1           
2    2.0,4.0
dtype: object

In [45]: df.c.groupby(df.a).apply(lambda x: '' if x.isnull().any() else ','.join(set(x.astype(str).values)))
Out[45]: 
a
1        foo
2    sha,bar
dtype: object
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I tried this `.isnull()`, but I didn't know I could use this `.any()` neither that `astype()` (I was verifying with .dtype)... The set was good to avoid duplicates. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help:

```
import numpy
df_new = df.replace(numpy.nan,' ', regex=True)
```

EDIT:

I think this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401295/using-python-to-remove-duplicated-contents-in-cells-in-excel) could work for you (just as an alternative to the answer of @Ami.

Comment: This is working great, but that's what I meant with ignore duplicates. It's returning now a bunch of commas. Ex: " , , , , , , , , "

Comment: Sorry I think I don't understand, what you want to have as output?

Comment: Sorry, @vlad.rad, I edited my question. I want to have only " " when there is no project and not ", , , , , , , , " or duplicate projects. I forgot to add in the boddy.

Comment: I guess I just needed to use set() in this answer
.apply(lambda x: ",".join(set(x)))

Comment: I have found another discussion to this topic on stack overflow, I have pasted the link into my edited answer. 
Good luck!